# how to prevent someone from invoking a method in a mBean deployed in the OSGI container

Tags: osgi, jmx, mbeans

I have the  osgi.core.framework mbean deployed into the OSGI container. This particular mbean has a method 'installBundleFromURL' which someone can use to deploy a malicious jar. I want to prevent anyone to invoke this particular method. Is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use permissions to verify the caller has been granted the required permission.

Comment: What if you want no one to use that method?

Comment: Delete the method would be best. Or change the method to immediately throw an exception.

Comment: This method is in a third party library. so cannot change the source code.

Comment: Then, if the object is available to anyone, you can't control who can call it from outside the object. All that may be possible is permissions since you can assign permissions to the mbean containing bundle that deny it the right to install a bundle.